# TCP Android Server and C# Client

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to create an `Android Server` and `Client on C#` base on `TCP Socket`. I want them both to send and received a `string(Data)` so I can make a command base on the given `string(Data)`. For the meantime, the Server can listen to incoming clients and the Clients can connect to Server. But I have `two` problem and i can't solve it.

**PROBLEMS:**
**1. When i try to send the `data` to Server, the Server was unable to `Read` it.

2. When the Client is `Disconnected`, the Server is giving me a loop of `Null`.**

I already try to Search about communicating C# and Android using TCP but i didn't found anything like what i need.

**The following code is for Android Server.**

I am having a loop of Null in class `CommunicationThread` when the client is Disconnected. I think it's because I am using a `while` for reading the `Data` from client, but since it become disconnected then it is resulting a `null`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tx1, tx_waiting;

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Handler updateConversationHandler, dg;
    Thread serverThread = null;
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tx1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tx_waiting = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tx_waiting);

        //Start the Server
        try{
            updateConversationHandler = new Handler();
            dg = new Handler();
            this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
            this.serverThread.start();
            tx_waiting.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d("Server Starting","Server Already Started.");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
            Log.d("Server Stop","Successfully Stopped the Server Without any Error.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Server Failed to Stop",e.toString());
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                Log.d("Server Thread","Server Thread Already Started.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();
                    Log.d("Server Socket","New Client is Connected");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private BufferedReader input;
        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
            try {
                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                Log.d("Input Stream","Input Stream Received!.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    String read = input.readLine();
                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
                    Log.d("Update Convers.","Conversation was Updating...");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;
        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
             Log.d("Client Data",msg.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

**The following code is for C# Client to Connect and Send the Data.**

```
            System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
            NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);

            Task f = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                //Connect the Client into Server
                try {
                    clientSocket.Connect(tb_ip.Text, int.Parse(tb_port.Text));
                }
                catch (Exception ezz) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Server Not Found.");
                }

                //Assuming that the CLient is Connected then Send a Sample Data
                try {
                    serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is Sample Data");
                    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
                    serverStream.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception er) {
                    Console.WriteLine(er.ToString());
                }
            });
```

I have no method yet for Sending the Data from Server to Client since I am just starting to make this thing works, But if you have anything that can help me about this then i will really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Why the server is unable to read it? does it throw any exceptions?

Comment: There's no Exceptions, I put a Log when there is a Data and it say the Data was received. `Log.d("Input Stream","Input Stream Received!.");` but the Data was not showing. In Server, the last Class will Log the received Data in `Log.d("Client Data",msg.toString());`. but it is not showing the expected result. just nothing, I am assuming that it will write like `Client Data: ______` in log, but even the Log is not showing, I am so confused of this, I don't know if the Class is not calling when the Data was received or the Server was unable to Read the Data.

Comment: But when the Client is Disconnected then it is showing the Log `Client Data: null`, it is Looping. So it means the `updateUIThread` is calling.